# Correct parameter types for select queries that use table valued functions

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2015, strongly-typed-dataset

My SQL Server 2012 contains a function `Get_Schedule`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Get_Schedule(
    @pProject_Id   AS INT,
    @pPeriod_Start AS DATETIME2,
    @pPeriod_End   AS DATETIME2)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN (
        SELECT
            42     AS Val1,
            'Foo'  AS Val2);
```

Visual Studio 2015's SQL Server Object Explorer shows the function parameters with the types as defined.

However when dragging the function to the strongly typed dataset designer the `DATETIME2` parameters are changed to `ANSISTRING` instead of  `System.DateTime` or `System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2`.

The `int` parameter, `@pProject_Id` *does* have the correct type.

This happens both when using a select statement for the table adapter to access the database and when creating new a stored procedure (the procedure itself does have the expected `DATATIME2` as parameter but the generated table adapter has `ansistring`).

How to have the correct parameter types in the generated table adapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the query and its table adapter:

- open the table adapter's properties;
- expand `SelectCommand`; and,
- edit the `Parameters` tot the correct type.

Comment: Just a warning to anyone adopting this method (which works) - if you subsequently change your query it will regenerate the command and reset the parameters back to their defaults.