# Why is my tableadaptor forcing a cast to string on my date column

Tags: c#, mysql, tableadapter

I have a table with dates, and varying data about that date like so.

```
WKDWKDDATE8 WKDDAYNM    WKDAGENO    WKDDAYNO    WKDDATE6    WEEKNO  WEEKRANGE       AWEEK
2019-05-15  WEDNESDAY   43580       3           AJ0515      384     05/12 - 05/18   NULL
2019-05-16  THURSDAY    43581       4           AJ0516      384     05/12 - 05/18   NULL
```

and heres what my table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WKD](
[WKDDATE8] [date] NOT NULL,
[WKDDAYNM] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[WKDAGENO] [int] NULL,
[WKDDAYNO] [int] NULL,
[WKDDATE6] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
[WEEKNO] [int] NULL,
[WEEKRANGE] [varchar](20) NULL,
[AWEEK] [varchar](1) NULL,
```

as you can see my `WKDDATE8` field is a `Date`.
In my C# application, im using `tableadaptors` to query this table by WKDDATE8 using `SELECT * FROM WKD WHERE WKDDATE8 = @WKDDATE8`, but for some reason my table wants a string https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUbkl.jpg .

now, this is where it gets fustrating. I can manually change the designer from string to datetime and run, it works fine, but then i run it again and i get a build error because the query wants a string, HOWEVER, if i let it go as a string, i get the obvious `cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string'`.

i am completely dumbfounded and lost as to why my program wants a string.

E: this is the code thats causing me problems. i didnt write this code, it was generated. changing it is pointless as it will change back on the second build, and i can see it casting my column as a string when it really shouldnt

```
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public virtual CACTUSDataSet.WKDDataTable GetDataByWKD8(string WKDDATE8) {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
        if ((WKDDATE8 == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("WKDDATE8");
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(WKDDATE8));
        }
        CACTUSDataSet.WKDDataTable dataTable = new CACTUSDataSet.WKDDataTable();
        this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Where be the source code?

Comment: Make sure that your column in your TableAdaptor is set to "DateTime" type. If you are using the visual editor, just click on the column name and there should be a type option in the properties window.

Comment: @BenAbraham it is set as `System.DateTime` as it should be

Comment: @drew added code, even though i didnt write it

Comment: Take a look at your `TableAdapter`, in `GetDataByWKD8` in parameters, if the type of `@WKDDATE8` parameter is `NVARCHAR` or `CHAR`, change it to `DateTime`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei i had it set to `Date`, figured id change it to `DateTime` as you mention and it seems that was the cause. Does VS treat `Date` as a string? kinda strange if it does. if you want some rep, please repost it as a answer. thanks for your help

Comment: @Multinerd I checked it and it seems the Dataset Designer creates string argument for date parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dataset Designer creates string argument for date parameters.

Take a look at your `DataSet`, for the table adapter and `GetDataByWKD8` command. In parameters, check if the `DbType` of `@WKDDATE8` is a string type like `AnsiString` then change the `Dbtype` to `Date` and `ProviderType` to `DateTime`, then your fill command will accept an input of type `DateTime`.

Highlight the query in the Designer and look at the properties tab to do this. Just hit the Properties collection and you'll get a dialogue where the DbType is set to AnsiString. You'll find DateTime2 near the bottom of the list if you need that one.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't get around the designer problem - this is a recent change I think because I'm having this problem with legacy XSDs that were fine. Now all DateTime2 columns have this happen to them regardless of anything manual I may do. It's annoying.

Comment: Never mind: this answer clarified it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888920/correct-parameter-types-for-select-queries-that-use-table-valued-functions

Comment: Surely you should not change the xml or c# code, I also mean using designer :)

Comment: I'd agree - I done enough XSD hacking to really not recommend it. I've added a little to your answer as I needed that help, it wasn't obvious to me :).

Comment: Oops! I thought it's obvious! Sorry about that :)

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Thanks for the feedback and editing to make it more clear :)

Comment: Btw I notice if your query does something like isnull(somefield, someotherfield) = SomeParameter then the XSD designer can't determine what type the SomeParameter is hence the AnsiString failsafe.